# Round of Accurately from the last value after decimal

Tags: sql-server, rounding

I have stuck (again) and looking for smart human beings of planet earth to help me out.

**Background**

I have an application which distributes the amounts to some users in a given percentage. Say I have $35000 and it will distribute the amounts to 3 users (A, B and C) in some ratio. So the amount distributed will be

A - 5691.05459265518

B - 14654.473815207

C - 14654.4715921378

which totals up to $35000

**The Problem**

I have to provide the results on the front end in 2 decimal spaces instead of float. So I use the round function of SQL Server with the precision value of 2 to convert these to 2 decimal spaces with rounding. But the issue is that when I total these values this comes out to be $34999.9999 instead of $35000.

[image: difference when rounding off]

**My Findings**

I searched a bit and found

> If the expression that you are rounding ends with a 5, the Round()
> function will round the expression so that the last digit is an even
> number. Here are some examples:
>
> Round(34.55, 1) - Result: 34.6 (rounds up)
>
> Round(34.65, 1) - Result: 34.6 (rounds down)

So technically the answer is correct but I am looking for a function or a way to round of the value exactly what it should have been. I found that if I start rounding off (if the value is less than 5 then leave the previous number else increment the previous digit by 1 ) from the last digit after the decimal and keep on backtracking while I am left with only 2 decimal places.

[image: rounding from last digit]

Please advise.

Comment: You can't round with losing precision while also keeping precision. Rounding `5691.05459265518` to `5691.06` is incorrect.

Comment: Your proposed rounding technique appears flawed. It would round `0.004555555555` to `0.01`. Do you think that's correct?

Comment: To further illustrate the point, the only way you'll get those numbers is by pretending you gave one member an extra cent (with that extra cent being taken from others). That's a terribly bad idea for what appears to be an accounting application. What you *could* do is delegate the rounding to excel. That is, fill the cell with the proper value, but style it so that excel rounds to 2 decimal places. That way, a total function referencing your cells will give the correct total, but visually, you'd round to 2 digits.

Comment: If you have any chance to update the application, you could make the changes there to distribute the amount with 2 decimal places. That way you need not do any thing during reporting.

Comment: Why not just use the original values and use formatting to round them?  The individual `Member` values will show as rounded to the nearest penny (Which will be slightly off because that's how math works) but your `Total` will still be correct.  Then add a caveat in your report somewhere that states `Rounded to nearest penny`

Comment: I would consider holding the $35000 in a table that holds shared pot amounts. The members table would have a foreign key to the pot amount they share and a column to hold the percentage they have been allocated from that amount. You would never have to hold a calculated amount.

Comment: Consider the set of distributions `0.046`, `0.047`, `0.047` to exactly distribute `0.14`. Even with your overly complicated rounding algorithm, this gives you `0.05`, `0.05`, `0.05` adding up to `0.15` -- one cent more than you have. There is no way to "solve" this problem by any trick of rounding individual numbers -- you'll have to decide how you want to handle the difference, but in most applications, it is of paramount importance that totals add up correctly with rounded amounts, even if this means the final amount is "off" from a desired value.

Comment: If you wanted to start off with an inviolable total (like, you *must* distribute *exactly* 35,000 to these three people) then the amounts they get must budge. You could sort them high to low and subtract them from 35,000 until the last participant gets slightly more or less than their percentage dictates. More complicated and fairer ways for distributing the difference are also possible. But this is really an issue of more or less money, not merely of rounding.

Comment: with all the comments above, I agree to each and every one of them. I am sorry for giving an inaccurate title for the question. I am quite sure this is not something I would have done either but this is how this was built. I think the only option I have is to format the number like excel that will have the complete value but only limit the display to 2 decimal spaces. Again, you guys are the reason Aliens have not attacked us. Kudos to your sharp minds.